# Uncompress GZIP http-response (using jersey client api, java)

Tags: java, jersey, gzip, jersey-1.0

Could someone tell me what I need to do in order to uncompress a GZIP content when getting the response from some Http-call.

To make the call I use the Jersey Client API, see code below:

```
String baseURI = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/answers/7539863?body=true&comments=false";
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource wr = client.resource(baseURI); 
ClientResponse response = null;
response = wr.get(ClientResponse.class);
String response_data = response.getEntity(String.class);

System.out.println(response_data);
```

However the output is GZIP’d and looks like:

```
{J?J??t??`$?@??????....
```

It would be good if I could implement the following:

- being able to detect whether content is GZIP’d or not;
- If not, process like normal in a String; if, so uncompress and get the content in String

Comment: For Jersey 2.0 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834028/what-is-the-jersey-2-0-equivalent-of-gzipcontentencodingfilter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply add [GZIPContentEncodingFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/GZIPContentEncodingFilter.html) to your client:

```
client.addFilter(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter(false));
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't retrieve the response as an entity. Retrieve it as an input stream and wrap it in a java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream:

```
GZipInputStream is = new GZipInputStream(response.getEntityInputStream());
```

Then read the uncompressed bytes yourself and turn it into a String.

Also, check whether the server is including the HTTP header `Content-Encoding: gzip`. If not, try including it in the response. Perhaps Jersey is smart enough to do the right thing.

Comment: thanks, but what if the content is not-GZIPed (i.e. could I implement a way to detect this, depending on the response received?)

Comment: If you can depend on the server to behave properly, you can check the Content-Encoding value. (Alternatively, the response might just set a mime type of application/x-gzip.) Use `response.getHeaders()` and test for the appropriate values. The only other thing I can think of is that if it seems to be garbage under one assumption, try the other.

Answer (score 1):

In Jersey 2.x (I use 2.26):

```
WebTarget target = ...
target.register(GZipEncoder.class);
```

Then `getEntity(String.class)` can be used on the response as usual.

Comment: There's no `getEntity(Class)` method in 2.x client. There is a `readEntity(Class)` method.