# What is the Jersey 2.0 equivalent of GZIPContentEncodingFilter

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

I am in the progress to migrate a Jerset 1.x client project to Jersey 2.0.

I found that `GZIPContentEncodingFilter` does not exist any longer. Is there something similar?

I stumbled over `GZIPEncoder` but am not sure how to plug it in.

In Jersey 1.17 I use:

```
WebResource r = ...
r.register(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
```

In Jersey 2.0 I search for somethink like:

```
WebTarget r = ...
r.register(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
```

Comment: Are you using jersey 2.0 on the server side as well? If so, may I ask how you got gzip-encoding to work? (I've posted a question regarding this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751014/gzip-encoding-in-jersey-2).)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately on the other side is a legacy system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
WebTarget r = ...
r.register(GZIPEncoder.class);
```

Comment: Hey, I have some more errors in my project. I will accept your answer when I'm finished and can try it. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me only if executed after r.register(EncodingFilter.class). The same calling sequence met in Jersey unit tests. See https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/tests/e2e/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/e2e/common/EncodingTest.java

Answer (score 4):

Most of details can be obtained from Jersey's own unit tests.
So to allow responses to be compressed using GZip or Deflate algorighms (in cost of increased CPU load and latency) you should use:

```
WebResource r = ...
r.register(EncodingFilter.class); // Allow to process encodings
r.register(GZIPEncoder.class);
r.register(DeflateEncoder.class);
```

See configure method in Jersey v2.x encoding unit test: [EncodingTest](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/tests/e2e/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/e2e/common/EncodingTest.java)

Answer (score 1):

In Jersey 2.x (I use 2.26):

```
WebTarget target = ...
target.register(GZipEncoder.class);
```

I did not have to include EncodingFilter/DeflateEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

Anotate method with @GZIP , It internally uses GZIP Encoder and remove 
GZIPContentEncodingFilter  from web.xml that solves problem

Comment: Could you please provide a link to `@GZIP`?

Comment: I tried resteasy has direct support http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/gzip.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is for the server not the client.  The OP is asking about the client.

Comment: This answer is specifically for RestEasy. @GZIP is not defined in Jersey server.