# GZIP encoding in Jersey 2 / Grizzly

Tags: jersey, gzip, grizzly

I can't activate gzip-encoding in my Jersey service. This is what I've tried:

1. Started out with the `jersey-quickstart-grizzly2` archetype from the [Getting Started Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html).
2. Added `rc.register(org.glassfish.grizzly.http.GZipContentEncoding.class);`

   (have also tried `rc.register(org.glassfish.jersey.message.GZipEncoder.class);`)
3. Started with `mvn exec:java`
4. Tested with `curl --compressed -v -o - http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource`

The result is the following:

```
> GET /myapp/myresource HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 zlib/1.2.3.4 ...
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Sun, 03 Nov 2013 08:07:10 GMT
< Content-Length: 7
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
Got it!
```

That is, despite `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` in the request, there is no `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response.

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the code like:

```java
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
        BASE_URI, rc, false);

CompressionConfig compressionConfig =
        httpServer.getListener("grizzly").getCompressionConfig();
compressionConfig.setCompressionMode(CompressionConfig.CompressionMode.ON); // the mode
compressionConfig.setCompressionMinSize(1); // the min amount of bytes to compress
compressionConfig.setCompressableMimeTypes("text/plain", "text/html"); // the mime types to compress

httpServer.start();
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick! I was on Grizzly 2.2.3 thought, so I didn't have `CompressConfig` but corresponding methods were available on `NetworkListener`. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You have to register the `org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.EncodingFilter` as well. This example enables `deflate` and `gzip` compression:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.DeflateEncoder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.GZipEncoder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.EncodingFilter;
...
private void enableCompression(ResourceConfig rc) {
    rc.registerClasses(
            EncodingFilter.class,
            GZipEncoder.class,
            DeflateEncoder.class);
}
```

This solution is jersey specific and works not only with Grizzly, but with the JDK Http server as well.

Comment: This was the only thing needed for me.