# ApacheConnector does not process request headers that were set in a WriterInterceptor

Tags: jersey, jersey-client

I am experiencing problems when configurating my Jersey `Client` with the `ApacheConnector`. It seems to ignore all request headers that I define in a `WriterInterceptor`. I can tell that the `WriterInterceptor` is called when I set a break point within `WriterInterceptor#aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext)`. Contrary to that, I can observe that the modification of an `InputStream` is preserved.

Here is a runnable example demonstrating my problem:

```java
public class ApacheConnectorProblemDemonstration extends JerseyTest {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JerseyTest.class.getName());
  private static final String QUESTION = "baz", ANSWER = "qux";
  private static final String REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_CLIENT = "foo-cl", REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE_CLIENT = "bar-cl";
  private static final String REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_INTERCEPTOR = "foo-ic", REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE_INTERCEPTOR = "bar-ic";
  private static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 100;
  private static final String PATH = "/";

  @Path(PATH)
  public static class TestResource {
    @POST
    public String handle(InputStream questionStream,
                         @HeaderParam(REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_CLIENT) String client,
                         @HeaderParam(REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_INTERCEPTOR) String interceptor) 
        throws IOException {
      assertEquals(REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE_CLIENT, client);
      // Here, the header that was set in the client's writer interceptor is lost.
      assertEquals(REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE_INTERCEPTOR, interceptor);
      // However, the input stream got gzipped so the WriterInterceptor has been partly applied.
      assertEquals(QUESTION, new Scanner(new GZIPInputStream(questionStream)).nextLine());
      return ANSWER;
    }
  }

  @Provider
  @Priority(Priorities.ENTITY_CODER)
  public static class ClientInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
      context.getHeaders().add(REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_INTERCEPTOR, REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE_INTERCEPTOR);
      context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(context.getOutputStream()));
      context.proceed();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
    enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
    return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected Client getClient(TestContainer tc, ApplicationHandler applicationHandler) {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = tc.getClientConfig() == null ? new ClientConfig() : tc.getClientConfig();
    clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, makeConnectionManager(MAX_CONNECTIONS));
    clientConfig.register(ClientInterceptor.class);
    // If I do not use the Apache connector, I avoid this problem.
    clientConfig.connector(new ApacheConnector(clientConfig));
    if (isEnabled(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC)) {
      clientConfig.register(new LoggingFilter(LOGGER, isEnabled(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY)));
    }
    configureClient(clientConfig);
    return ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
  }

  private static ClientConnectionManager makeConnectionManager(int maxConnections) {
    PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxConnections);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnections);
    return connectionManager;
  }

  @Test
  public void testInterceptors() throws Exception {
    Response response = target(PATH)
        .request()
        .header(REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_CLIENT, REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE_CLIENT)
        .post(Entity.text(QUESTION));
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    assertEquals(ANSWER, response.readEntity(String.class));
  }
}
```

I want to use the `ApacheConnector` in order to optimize for concurrent requests via the `PoolingClientConnectionManager`. Did I mess up the configuration?

PS: The exact same problem occurs when using the `GrizzlyConnector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research, I assume that this is rather a misbehavior in the default `Connector` that uses a `HttpURLConnection`. As I explained in this [other self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765582/how-to-make-jersey-use-gzip-compression-for-the-response-message-body) of mine, the [documentation states](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html):

> Whereas filters are primarily intended to manipulate request and
>   response parameters like HTTP headers, URIs and/or HTTP methods,
>   interceptors are intended to manipulate entities, via manipulating
>   entity input/output streams

A `WriterInterceptor` is not supposed to manipulate the header values while a `{Client,Server}RequestFilter` is not supposed to manipulate the entity stream. If you need to use both, both components should be bundled within a `javax.ws.rs.core.Feature` or within the same class that implements two interfaces. (This can be problematic if you need to set two different `Priority`s though.)

All this is very unfortunate though, since `JerseyTest` uses the `Connector` that uses a `HttpURLConnection` such that all my unit tests succeeded while the real life application misbehaved since it was configured with an `ApacheConnector`. Also, rather than suppressing changes, I wished, Jersey would throw me some exceptions. (This is a general issue I have with Jersey. When I for example used a *too new* version of the `ClientConnectionManager` where the interface was renamed to `HttpClientConnectionManager` I simply was informed in a one line log statement that all my configuration efforts were ignored. I did not discover this log statement til very late in development.)